# How to scan and repair RAID 5 using mdadm

Tags: linux, unix, raid, raid-5

[image]

Raid5 on a server is having problems the last two times I rebooted.  CentOS does boot up after 10-15 minutes.  ***Is there a way I can scan the raid and repair it?*** I was reading the man page and `mdadm --scan` caught my attention but my command was unsuccessful.  The raid has no data on it or anything at the moment.

Could this be one of the HDs failed? 2/3 drives are **VERY** old but aren't used much.

Then I saw the assemble option but the raid is already assembled no?

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sdd[1] sde[3] sdc[0]
      3906762752 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

And

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md?*
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Jul  4 00:09:25 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 3906762752 (3725.78 GiB 4000.53 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953381376 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent
 
     Intent Bitmap : Internal
 
       Update Time : Wed Sep 30 22:49:32 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0
 
            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K
 
Consistency Policy : bitmap
 
              Name : orcacomputers.orcainbox:0  (local to host orcacomputers.orcainbox)
              UUID : 4ca9118c:3a557d0f:db723ff2:e8b9a521
            Events : 5327
 
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
       1       8       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
       3       8       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
```

A little later,

```
lsblk /dev/sdf
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdf         8:80     0  7.3T  0 disk
```

And

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sdf*
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdf





NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0   200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0   446G  0 part  
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0  31.4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 364.5G  0 lvm   /home
sdb               8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk  /run/media/orca/ssd2
sdc               8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─md0             9:0    0   3.7T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid5
sdd               8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─md0             9:0    0   3.7T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid5
sde               8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─md0             9:0    0   3.7T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid5
sdf               8:80   0   7.3T  0 disk
```

The hard drives look good, they have not failed as per

```
/dev/sda
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdb
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdc
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdd
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sde
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdf
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command



   /dev/sdf is the combination of sdc sdd sde
```

Here is a list of drives:

```
    /dev/sda         447.1G
    /dev/sdb         447.1G
    /dev/sdc         1.8T
    /dev/sdd         1.8T
    /dev/sde         1.8T
    /dev/sdf         7.3T
```

Thanks for any help.  I did not set up this raid5.

Comment: Please add `cat /proc/mdstat` to your question. And `mdadm --detail /dev/md*`. Both preferably not as a screenshot but as a proper copy and paste because it's really important the details are crystal clear. Your `/dev/sdf` has failed and I'm curious to see why it's not been kicked out of the array. (By the way, I would suggest you don't try out `mdadm` commands on a live system without understanding what they do)

Comment: Thanks for response. I had to pastebin the output because it was too long | https://pastebin.com/rvVwjqtM

Comment: What does `lsblk /dev/sdf` tell you should be on the disk? And what about `mdadm --examine /dev/sdf*`

Comment: lsblk /dev/sdf

NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdf    8:80   0  7.3T  0 disk 

sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdf*
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdf.

Comment: Please would you add that to your question, where you can also format it with the `{}` button in the editor. What this is telling you is that there's nothing obvious on the disk. What other disks do you think should be in its RAID array (we've already discounted `sdc`, `sdd`, and `sde`)

Comment: Sure, sdc, sdd, sde make up the raid5 sdf

Comment: Not according to the RAID subsystem they don't

Comment: As @roaima said - not according to mdadm and mdstat - that is represented by /dev/md0. Also, sdc,sde and sdf are 1.8tb = a 3.6 tb RAID disk, not a 7.3tb one. Are you maybe running both hardware and software raid?  What does "smartctl -i /dev/sdf" say?

Comment: Not using a software raid.

`$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdf

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.`

Comment: Don't you think that "_not using a software raid_" is important information? Important enough perhaps to have mentioned it in your question?

Comment: It looks to me like you've got hardware RAID and software RAID on the same physical disks, possibly with the software RAID presenting `/dev/md0` and the hardware RAID presenting `/dev/sdf`. At this point I have no idea what you've actually got configured. TBH if that's true I'm amazed you haven't lost all your data already

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sdf has failed and needs to be replaced. The buffer I/O errors are coming from the disk, not mdadm.

AFAIK there is no repair for mdadm as there is nothing to repair, but there is likely a verify option (which I don't think helps you) and, ifckurse, you can remove the failed device and add a new one.

Comment: sdf is the 7.3TB raid.  sdc,sdd,sde make sdf

Comment: No its not. See above.

Comment: You are correct.  I feel like a total knob.  The 7.3TB is my external HD, not the Raid5.  I had the the external hard drive upside down on the ground.  So I unplugged it, turned it right side up then tested it on my laptop successfully; it worked, then put it back on production server and errors went away.  *face palm* So many moving parts to my business...Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The photograph of your console shows myraid errors from `/dev/sdf`. The output of `/proc/mdstat` shows that the RAID5 in question is built from `/dev/sdd`, `/dev/sde`, and `/dev/sdc`, with no missing component.

Therefore the RAID5 is not at risk. You have something else using `/dev/sdf`, and it is this that will be losing data. (Maybe an unassembled RAID array?)

Comment: The raid array was assembled previously.  Is there a way to see what is trying to use sdf? I haven't done anything with this RAID yet, I was just trying to see if I could get it to show up in "Other Locations" in the File GUI on CentOS